# How to bring changes from subversion repo to current directory

Tags: linux, svn

For bash command on linux.
I was thinking perhaps svn import but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current directory is already a working copy of your repo just use

```
    cd <name of your folder>
    svn update
```

with a terminal where you changed into your directory before. You can see wheter the folder is a working dir by the presence of ".svn"-Folder in it. Type

```
    ls -a
```

If you see the ".svn"-Folder, it should be a working copy.

Otherwhise the easiest way is to checkout the folder from the repository with

```
    svn checkout svn://your-repo/your-path/
```

Make sure to do this in a new/seperate Folder in order not to overwrite existing data! This will checkout a new working copy of your repo-folder selected in the given path.

You can then update the folder or commit changes simply by the commands

```
    svn update
```

or

```
    svn commit
```

from within the directory to/from your repo.

Import means bringing new files into your repository. If I understand your question correctly, you want to do the opposite. If you want to have the latest version of a file on your local machine it's an update.